# Minimum iOS version for Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am looking and I can't find what minimum iOS version GCM handles. On [official website](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) it just says *how to install with pods*. CocoaPods documentation does not say what minimum version of iOS version can be. Does anybody know what minimum version of iOS Google Cloud Messaging can handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [podspec for GoogleCloudMessaging](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/GoogleCloudMessaging/1.0.3/GoogleCloudMessaging.podspec.json) `platform` entry for version 1.0.3 says the iOS version is 7.

[The OS version specified in `platform` would be the minimum version](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#platform).

Comment: So to be clear, it can't be used with iOS6 whatsoever?

Comment: that's my interpretation of what the podspec syntax (in the second link) means.